# Android: Action Bar being covered up by scrolling SurfaceView

Tags: android, android-actionbar, scrollview, surfaceview

In my Android project, I have a SurfaceView nested inside a scrollview. If I scroll the scrollview down (such that part of it is obscured by the action bar), then select the action bar, then the SurfaceView will be brought to the front of the z-ordering, in front of the action bar as well.

Is there a way to bring the action bar to the front, or the SurfaceView to the back, in terms of z-ordering?

Answer (score 0):

surfaceview.setZOrderOnTop(false)